# Why was my bounty removed?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, bounty

I think I had at least one day more. I read a couple of hours ago "your bounty will expire tomorrow" and usually the hours are shown, for example "it will expire in 10 hours", etc.
It was for [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17006/leaving-the-food-out-to-cool-off-after-cooking).

Comment: I have no idea how to even tell. Maybe Aaronut or Hobodave will know.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104919/bounty-auto-awarded-after-6-days/104941#104941

Comment: @Sam: Seems we mods can't refund a bounty after it's ended, so can you or one of the devs please follow up?

Comment: @aaronut it's ok, i can live without the bounty, it was an accident

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to call this a bug, pending confirmation or explanation from the dev team.

If you check the [history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/17006/revisions) you will see the following text:

> **Bounty Ended** with no winning answer

The timestamp on this event is 2011-08-30 17:37. The bounty was started on 2011-08-24 18:03:36. That's actually *less than 6 days* and bounties should expire after 7 days.

If it does turn out to be a bug then we can refund it (I'd like to make sure first).

**Update:** As per Sam's comment, [it was a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104919/bounty-auto-awarded-after-6-days/104941#104941).

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was mine, I just started another bounty on that question, let me know who you want me to pick.

Comment: ok, i gave points to the answers Frankie 2.5, Aaron 3, JasonTrue 2.5 So Aaron wins the bounty, but give it now .Thank you